# What should be the best way to change StatusBar background colour and preferredStatusBarStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-statusbar

My requirements are like, in my app there are two flows, so for both flows value of preferredStatusBarStyle & StatusBar background colour are different. So if I have 40 `viewControllers`, 20 VCs have same values and 20VCs have different values than first 20 values.

For now I am changing values in each view controllers, like this:-

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = AppColors.themeStatusColor
}
```

and in info.plist I did this:-

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

Can u guys tell me any way so I can write these lines of code only two places and I can achieve my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BaseVCBlue: UIViewController {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.default
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
}



class BaseVc: UIViewController {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = AppColors.themeStatusColor
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

But Most important one:- 
There’s one case where this won’t work and that is if your controller is embedded in a navigation stack . Reason being that iOS wants the parent controller (and NOT the child controller) to decide what kind of status bar one needs to show, then do this also:-

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}
```

Now u can change easily and this will work perfectly :)

Comment: bro but what about preferredStatusBarStyle?

Comment: i can change only background color via this, not preferredStatusBarStyle, but i need to change both at the same time :(

Comment: @VipulKumar check now.

Comment: preferredStatusBarStyle this doesn't change yr, background color can be changed easily, but i don't know why preferredStatusBarStyle is not changing accordingly.

Comment: What does it mean it should change.

Comment: What are you expecting from this.

Comment: see i want ""preferredStatusBarStyle = .default"" for one VC and  ""preferredStatusBarStyle = .lightContent"" for one VC

Comment: You want same across the app.

Comment: Or it should change as per view controller.

Comment: as per view controller.

Comment: bro i got the problem, There’s one case where this won’t work and that is if your controller is embedded in a navigation stack . Reason being that iOS wants the parent controller (and NOT the child controller) to decide what kind of status bar one needs to show!

Comment: and now if i am doing this:-

Comment: extension UINavigationController {
   open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
   }
}

Comment: now i can do change the value of preferredStatusBarStyle as per view controller.

Comment: thnx for help :)

Comment: Then create 2 BaseViewController and both has to set diff style and user this 2 overide this preferredStatusBarStyle in both the baseviewcontroller's and use it

Comment: yeah bro doing like it now :)

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: plz see it and approve it :)

Comment: Approved check now.

Answer (score 1):

Create Base view controller(root) and extent it.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .lightContent
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = AppColors.themeStatusColor
   }
}
```

**Use:**

```
class MYSecondFlowController: BaseViewController {

}
```

Comment: bro i am already doing it, but in my case i need to set one value for 20 VCs and one different value for rest 20 VCs.

Comment: then make another Base controller

Comment: self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

Comment: @VipulKumar Yes

Comment: bro i don't why but backgroundColor changes only, not preferredStatusBarStyle, :(

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating two ViewController like below:

// For 20 VC with blue status bar

```
class BaseVCBlue: UIViewController {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

// For 20 VC with red status bar

```
class BaseVCRed: UIViewController {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

when you need blue status bar extend blue and when you want red extend red.

Comment: bro i don't why but backgroundColor changes only, not preferredStatusBarStyle, :(